# Messed up path in centOS

Tags: linux, shell, path, centos

I'm a Linux noob. By mistake, I ran :

```
export PATH=/root/anaconda3/bin
```

I figure I have changed the value of "PATH" by not using '$PATH:'. Now everytime I press enter, it says sed not installed. I can't even get into sudo anymore.

---

```
echo $PATH
```

still shows -

```
:/home/adi/bin:/home/adi/bin
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Linux usage questions can be posted to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: So just change PATH to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you put this change into your .bash_profile or .bashrc file, it will not persist the next time you log in.  Just log out and log back in and all shall be right with the world.